# I want each item to have a spacing between them, im using Reactstrap table

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

im adding a `style` inside `tr` and it didn't work. My goal is to add margins in every each item.

```js
export default function StoreListing() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [dropdownType, setDropdownType] = useState(false);
  const toggleType = () => setDropdownType(prevState => !prevState);
  const [dropdownSize, setDropdownSize] = useState(false);
  const toggleSize = () => setDropdownSize(prevState => !prevState);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItem(data);
  }, []);

  const renderItems = () => {
    return item.map(res => (
      <tr key={res.id} style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
        <td>
          <div>
            <img src={res.img} className={'test-img'} alt={res.img}></img>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colSpan={5}>
          <div>{res.display_name}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Php {res.price}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="quantity" id="quantity"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownType} toggle={toggleType} size="sm">
            <DropdownToggle caret>Type</DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem>Small</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Medium</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Large</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownSize} toggle={toggleSize} size="sm">
            <DropdownToggle caret>Size</DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem>Small</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Medium</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Large</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        </td>
        <td>
          <EditIcon style={{ marginRight: '15px' }} />
          <ClearIcon />
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div className="test-container">
      <div className="test-table-container">
        <Table borderless hover responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th colSpan={5}>Name</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Size</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{renderItems()}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't find an answer but I made this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-react-table-forked-g8mfj?file=/src/storeList.js) if it can help somebody to find an answer.
On the other hand you have an issue on dropdown toggle function. If you click on one DropDown of your table every dropdown with the same type will toggle to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add margin to `<tr>` tag :
One solution is to apply style to the `Table` by passing `style={{ borderCollapse: "separate", borderSpacing: "0 20px" }}` like this:

```
 <Table
          borderless
          hover
          responsive
          style={{ borderCollapse: "separate", borderSpacing: "0 20px" }}
        >
```

and you can remove your styl in the `<tr>`tag.
here the [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-react-table-forked-45x8l?file=/src/storeList.js:2397-2546)